# Codeigniter table join and count, how to get count 0 return?

Tags: codeigniter, count

I have two tables.

### table A (  id, title, department )

```
       1,  title 1 ,  1
       2,  title 2 ,  1
       3,  title 3 ,  2
```

### table B (  uid, mid , is_active  )

```
       1, 1, 1
       2, 1, 1
       3, 3, 1
```

And here is my query statement:

```
          $this->db->select("  id, title ")  
                   ->select('   count(  B.uid ) AS B_count   ')
                   //->select('   IFNULL( COUNT( `B.uid`), 0) AS B_count ', false)
                   //->select( " IFNULL( COUNT(DISTINCT B.uid) AS B_count , 0 )" )
                   ->join( 'B', '   B.mid = A.id   ' ,  'left')
                   ->where('department', 1 )
                   ->where('B.is_active' , 1 )
                   ->limit(  $limit, $offset );     

    $this->db->group_by( array("B.mid") );         

    return $this->get_all();
```

And i expect to get result like this

### id, title  , B_count

```
    1, title 1, 2
    2, title 2, 0
```

However i can get only the first record but no the second record.
And i already have tried IFNULL function and left join tables. 
really don't know how to solve the issue. 
Does anyone know the solution or what the problem is?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `get('A')` instead of `get_all()`